# Why don't the Boston investigators have any ready-made place to investigate the marathon bombings?

Tags: plot-explanation, patriots-day

In [Patriot's Day](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4572514/), the Boston investigators select some empty warehouse to investigate the marathon bombings.

Actually, the warehouse was totally empty and people started arranging all the electronic stuff suddenly.

[image]

I mean why don't they have a ready-made place for investigation purposes like the Pentagon does etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Because it's an unforeseen event.**

You don't maintain large expensive offices or facilities **just in case**...it's not fiscally responsible and that's a big deal for local law enforcement who have budgets to maintain and adhere to.

Equally, this was, as I recall, a multi-jurisdictional task force including Boston PD (and other local police), FBI, Homeland Security, ATF and no doubt others so the question of *who* would have the responsibility of maintaining the facility also arises.

On the other hand, finding an empty warehouse that can be activated and used by many forces and departments *at the same*, all of whom can get set up quickly, makes much more sense.